# Spring Boot Actuator javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have added Spring Boot Actuator to my project and configured with:

```
#Spring Boot Actuator
management.contextPath: /actuator
```

Also, I have added following rules to my Spring Security:

```
.antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("PERMISSION_READ_ACTUATOR_DATA")
```

Right now, when I accessing `/actuator/health` everything works fine but when I try to access for example `/actuator/autoconfig` together with 403 Forbidden (that is totally  fine!) I also receive a following exception into console:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:205) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
```

How to correctly handle this exception without my console/log bombing with an exception above ? Is it possible to return some JSON error instead of looking for a error path ?

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: You can try replacing  *@Controller* with *@RestController*